# Enviar Email + Certificado Digital com Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou precisando enviar e-mails assinado com certificado digital com node.

Alguém consegue me dar um direcionamento de como implementar isso?

Comment: Penso que deveria dar uma olhada no [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer).

Comment: Até vi Jonatas, o problema é que não encontro um exemplo de como assinar e enviar o email. Pro java tem o BouncyCastle mas ainda não consegui implementar nenhum exemplo tb

Comment: Consegui resolver usando o módulo **smime** e **nodemailer**. Basicamente realizo a assinatura do conteúdo do e-mail gravo em um arquivo e depois a anexo a mensagem para o envio.

Comment: Seria interessante editares a pergunta, re-abrirmos e dares uma resposta. Queres ajudar nisso?